# Electric Field in Conductor Zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gauss-law

My textbook claims that the electric field in a conductor is zero in a static condition, as otherwise, a current would flow. But what if I go infinitely close to a proton; there will be an electric field right? Is my idea wrong or is the textbook flawed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a conductor (perfect conductor *or* imperfect conductor) in steady-state there is no *macroscopic* electric field, i.e. if you *average* the electric field over a volume that is big enough to include many atoms, the result is zero. That's what the textbook meant. You are certainly right that there are nonzero *microscopic* electric fields, e.g. the large field between the nuclei and their surrounding core electrons.

Answer (score 1):

Your textbook is talking about a *perfect conductor*, a *model* of a real conductor.  In a perfect conductor charge is considered to be chopped up into infinitely tiny portions.  Charge in a perfect conductor is a continuum, not quantized as we know charge in real conductors to be.  There are no discrete charges ... electrons or protons ... to get close to.

Comment: But why is reality so similar to this theoretical depiction? Real charges aren't infinitesmal, and yet, the electric field still seems to be zero.